# Programming Sqoop: v1.4.x or v1.99.x

Tags: maven, sqoop, sqoop2, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I'm using Cloudera Quickstart VM CDH 5.5.0 and I'm trying to do some custom Java code for Sqoop in a Maven project. However, I'm a bit confused about the two versions of Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sqoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqoop</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sqoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.99.5</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to dig to Sqoop's documentation, it seems that v1.99.x is related to [Sqoop2](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.5/). Sqoop2 is not yet encouraged to be used, according to [Cloudera here](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_sqoop_vs_sqoop2.html).

Furthermore, I can only get jars when using v1.99.x dependency, but not v1.4.x.

So which one should I be using if I want to do Sqoop programming? What's the difference between the two versions?

Answer (score 0):

I expect that this post can help you: http://ingest.tips/2014/10/21/sqoop-1-or-sqoop-2/ .

Mainly Sqoop2 is trying to add a better way to manage your jobs, and now they are working in  v1.99.x until they release the v2.00. 
If you want know more about that you could take a look of their roadmap: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SQOOP/Sqoop+2+Roadmap